# MediaElement doesn't play sound (Minimum Viable Example)

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml, audio

I'm developing a `Windows App` (Windows 8.1). In my `xaml` I have a `MediaElement` linked to a `.wav` file in the `/Assets` folder. I'd like to play the sound when I click on a button, but I can't achieve it. This is a minimum viable example that reproduces the issue. Can you help me?

This is the XAML file:

```
<Page
    x:Class="TrySoundsDesktop.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TrySoundsDesktop"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock FontSize="50" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            TRY PLAY SOUND
        </TextBlock>
        <MediaElement x:Name="clickSound"                      
                      Loaded="clickSound_Loaded"
                      MediaFailed="clickSound_MediaFailed"
                      MediaOpened="clickSound_MediaOpened"
                      MediaEnded="clickSound_MediaEnded"
                      AudioCategory="ForegroundOnlyMedia"                      
                      Height="100" 
                      Width="100" 
                      Opacity="1"
                      Source="/Assets/applause.wav"
                      AutoPlay="False"
                      />
        <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="CLICK TO PLAY SOUND"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

And this is the code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234238

namespace TrySoundsDesktop
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();            
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {            
            clickSound.Play(); //The sound doesn't play
        }

        private void clickSound_MediaFailed(object sender, ExceptionRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Not fired
        }

        private void clickSound_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Not fired
        }

        private void clickSound_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Not fired
        }

        private void clickSound_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //THIS METHOD FIRES
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see it's a very basic example. But it doesn't work. Thank you in advance.

Comment: In WPF you would need to have the file in the Bin folder or sub-folders in order to achieve what you are trying to do. Are you Copying the Resource in the bin folder? This is normally under the properties as "Copy to Output Directory"; this allows you to do the type of referencing you are doing in the XAML.

Comment: I went to the "/Assets/applause.wav" properties window and I set the "Copy to output directory" row as "Copy always" but it still doesn't work. I tried also with "Copy if newer" but nothing changes. Can you try my simple example here above on your Visual Studio to confirm that it doesn't work? Thank you for helping me.

Comment: I have an example working in WPF as we speak but I do not have access to the 8.1 store apps. I do notice that the your source you have an extra '/' char in the beginning of your string. It should look like this:  Source="Assets/applause.wav". In WPF that will cause it to fail to load

Comment: Unfortunately also removing extra initial '/' nothing changes.

Comment: Sorry that didn't help, I have a sample of a WPF application that is currently working on my machine. Here is a gist it incase you want to see it work in WPF. [GIST](https://gist.github.com/ScFix/91de43633fb16549adb2)

Comment: Oh man. I must thank you because thanks to your GIST example I found the solution. I ran your example and it fired an Exception saying that I haven't Windows Media Player 10 installed on my pc. And that is required. I have installed it and now all works great. Clearly, the creepy stuff (really really creepy) is that the Exception doesn't get fired on Windows 8.1 Store App. And this is very bad. Thank you again.

Comment: Glad I could help with your solution. That is a very odd that you would need to have that installed to use those Elements.